# Faster way to union table SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have TABLE_A

```
mode          bank_id        amount
'Outgoing'    1              100        
'Incoming'    1              200
'Outgoing'    1              300
'Incoming'    2              200
```

I need to turn it into

```
 from_bank_id          to_bank_id        amount
 1                     null              100        
 null                  1                 200
 1                     null              300        
 null                  2                 200
```

Right now I am doing this

```
  SELECT 
      amount, 
      NULL AS from_bank_id,
      bank_id AS to_bank_id 
    FROM TABLE_A WHERE mode = 'Incoming'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
      amount, 
      NULL AS to_bank_id,
      bank_id AS from_bank_id 
    FROM TABLE_A WHERE mode = 'Outgoing'
```

This sql works and give me the output I want. Just reaching out to see if there is a better way to achieve this without querying the table twice?

This is the first part query for second part [Reducing number of query for inner join when joining base on same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47231308/reducing-number-of-query-for-inner-join-when-joining-base-on-same-table?noredirect=1#comment81413468_47231308)

Comment: Note that there's nothing inherently wrong using a `UNION` for this, and indeed a `UNION ALL` will be faster and allow results to be returned immediately (instead of buffering all results before returning).

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT
    ( CASE WHEN mode = 'Outgoing' THEN bank_id ELSE NULL END ) AS from_bank_id,
    ( CASE WHEN mode = 'Incoming' THEN bank_id ELSE NULL END ) AS to_bank_id,
    amount
FROM
    table_a
```

PostgreSQL's `CASE` expression allows `ELSE NULL` to be omitted with the same behavior (emphasis mine):

> https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html
>   If no WHEN condition yields true, the value of the CASE expression is the result of the ELSE clause. **If the ELSE clause is omitted and no condition is true, the result is null**.

The parentheses can also be omitted:

So the query can be syntactically simplified to:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN mode = 'Outgoing' THEN bank_id END AS from_bank_id,
    CASE WHEN mode = 'Incoming' THEN bank_id END AS to_bank_id,
    amount
FROM
    table_a
```

...which is slightly more readable.

Comment: Thank you! I knew I can make use of CASE somehow. Thanks for making it clear! Also, is this alot faster than the way I am doing it? I want to know how to compare sql statement : ) Is it just simply how many query is ran?

Comment: @Zanko It's impossible to say for certain if one way is faster than another purely from code. You need to benchmark/profile your code yourself. It also depends on indexing, how data is physically arranged on disk, DBMS caching, and so on. You can start by looking at the execution plan (`EXPLAIN`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-explain.html )

Comment: It's possible use COALESCE as well

Comment: @dai, if the index is on "mode" does CASE WHEN mode ="something" make use of the index?

Comment: @Zanko I think that depends on your definition of "faster". Overall, and generally speaking, compared to the query with the `UNION ALL` operator this will be faster as you're not hitting the table twice. But as @Dai points out, benchmarking on the executing machine is the only true way to measure performance gains/losses.

Comment: @Zank that depends on if the index is covering the other columns involved.

Comment: @pim yea I guess the word "faster" is too vague. Since my data is not that big, I think I should be focusing more on reducing query to database as much as possible

Comment: @Zanko I wouldn't say that! I think that's everyone's go to word in these cases. Put it this way, I "knew" what you meant. I would agree with your last statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this more efficiently (and easily) with a [`CASE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql) expression.

```
select
    case 
        when mode = 'Outgoing' then bank_id 
        else null
    end as from_bank_id
    ,case 
        when mode = 'Incoming' then bank_id 
        else null
    end as to_bank_id
    ,amount
from
    TABLE_A
```