# Reducing number of query for inner join when joining base on same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Part 2 follow up of [Faster way to union table SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47231035/faster-way-to-union-table-sql)

I have TABLE_A

```
 from_bank_id          to_bank_id        amount
 1                     null              100        
 null                  1                 200
 1                     null              300        
 null                  2                 200
```

I have TABLE_B

```
bank_id      name
1            'BOA'
2            'SOME_BANK'
```

I need to output

```
 from_bank_id  to_bank_id   amount   from_bank_name  to_bank_name
 1             null         100     'BOA'            null
 null          1            200      null            'BOA'
 1             null         300     'BOA'            null      
 null          2            200      null            'SOME_BANK'
```

Right now I am doing

```
SELECT 
   t1.* 
   t2.name as from_bank_name,
   t3.name as to_bank_name
   FROM TABLE_A as t1
   LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_B as t2 ON t1.from_bank_id = t2.bank_id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_B as t3 ON t1.to_bank_id = t3.bank_id
```

1) Is there a more elegant way of achieving this?
2) How many query to database am I making to TABLE_B? I am guessing 2? one for each join?

Comment: this looks familiar ;) -- I would say that no, the way you're doing is theoretically the appropriate way. If you have a table like in your [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47231035/faster-way-to-union-table-sql/47231077#47231077) with a singular `bank_id` column, then you could accomplish this with one join.

Comment: @pim yea its actually kind of follow up :) I was constructing the last table as first part and now i need to do this second part. With this thought in mind do you know how I can acheive the first two part together more elegantly?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, not really. If you theoretically had a table with a singular `bank_id` then you could accomplish this with a single join to the table with the bank names.

I think it's also worth pointing out that this is a VERY basic query, and you might be over optimizing prematurely. I think Jeff Atwood's (he's a pretty smart/successful guy) [article](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/) on micro-optimization might be a good read for you.

In the [off-chance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47231035/faster-way-to-union-table-sql/47231077#47231035) you have a table like I mention above, this would work:

```
create table tblA 
(
    bank_id int,
    amount int,
    mode varchar(10)
);

create table tblB
(
    bank_id int,
    name varchar(10)
);

select
    case 
        when mode = 'Outgoing' then bank_id 
        else null
    end as from_bank_id
    case 
        when mode = 'Outgoing' then name
        else null
    end as from_bank_name
    ,case 
        when mode = 'Incoming' then bank_id 
        else null
    end as to_bank_id
    ,case 
        when mode = 'Incoming' then name
        else null
    end as to_bank_name
    ,amount
from
(
    select
        a.*
        ,b.name
    from
        tblA a
    left join
        tblB b
        on b.bank_id = a.bank_id
);
```

Comment: thanks! Yea most of the time I am just looking for confirmation that I am doing something correctly and not too horrible :P I'll give the article a read. It just feels very odd to call the same table TWICE when you are just basically using it to populate one column.

Comment: I just read up. Although it seems like an overkill but I can create a Materialized view to avoid querying the database twice right? At least the table will be in memory?

Comment: You can for sure. But given you're executing this in one batch. I would say the gain will be nominal.